# Can't see the result of magicquotes - magic_quotes_gpc = on

Tags: php

I have changed my ini file to turn on magicquotes and checked phpinfo()- it is on for local and master values.

I setup a test page:

```
<? echo $_GET['test']; ?>
```

And with

```
http://mysite.com/test.php?test="'
```

The result in source didn't have any backslashes added.

Comment: it isn't that, just checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
magic_quotes_gpc = on
magic_quotes_sybase = off
```

Comment: I am not depending on it, that doesn't answer my question!

Comment: Umm, just testing it? However, what is your PHP version?

Comment: it is version 5.3 -I know it is depracated but not removed until 5.4

Comment: @user1166981 Then what "is" your question? What is your desired result you wish to have? Your question is vague. You need to be more concise.

Comment: @Fred - clearly that is your problem, since Certain just answered it correctly

Comment: @user1166981 That is my **"problem"**? I can do without that type of remark sonny boy. Next time, I'll know what **"not"** to do.

Comment: @Fred don't be rude to people and you won't get rudeness back- old man

Comment: @user1166981 **ahem**, I doubt that very much. If you call my comments rude, then you wouldn't last 5 seconds in the same room with me. Btw, here's what we call `sarcasm`; **"did you start getting tired and/or lost patience, after spending a whole 120 seconds of your life, researching your problem?"**. Now that could fall under the `rude` category. **Now listen to me good**: First I wasn't "rude" and second, you should start learning the proper use of the English language including what the words in a sentence actually mean. Now buzz off and go back to work, your McDonald's manager is pissed.

Comment: @user1166981 Older than you, that's for sure and a lot more experience in many fields (many of which has not been posted in my profile, which I thank you for having read, might I add. It's clear that I've done a lot more in one day, than you'll ever achieve in a year.

Comment: @Fred since you obviously are insecure, I will be the bigger man, feel free to reply, I won't be reading it.

Comment: @user1166981 You can have the last word, if that will make you happy. I will tell you this, at least I'm getting "some" tonight, are you? LMFAO!!!! Phoque I'm good.

Comment: @user1166981 Not "insecure", I just love **grinding my teeth** and annoy the phoque out of you, little brat phoque.